# Horizontally to center two columns of buttons in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, swift4

I am new to app development and I am working on my constraints for different sized devices. I am trying to find a solution for how I can horizontally align two columns of buttons.  In the attached screen you will see that my two columns of buttons are aligned (like I want them) but they are not centered in the middle of the view.   Any help would be appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jsjP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all two columns of buttons in a view and then make that view horizontally centered. Make the buttons fill that holding view(or superview), so do not put fixed width and height for the super view of those buttons. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: That was the solution I needed. Thanks a million for your help!